# Rails 4, links like in Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In Gmail you see links with tokens, like:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#sent/1qqq4364396c1b5bbxba

I would like to use these in my Rails application.

In this way users can not enter their own links and the site is better protected.

Comment: Actually, rails uses similar mechanism in background for protection against CSRF, you could read details at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Comment: How does adding a hash to the url make it more protected?

Comment: Let me explain: article/edit/1 edits article with id=1. When a user changes the url in article/edit/2 the edit of article 2 is started, and you have to check internally whether the user may edit article with id=2